# Drop down list with values from database shows empty in Liferay

Tags: jsp, liferay

I want to display values in the drop-down list which comes from the database. The code is as follows in the `<form>`:

```
<aui:select id="empName" name="empName">

<%
Employee employee;
Employee newEmployee = new EmployeeImpl();
int totalEmployees = EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.getEmployeesCount();
for(int i=0; i<totalEmployees;i++) {
%>

<aui:option name = "opt" value ='<%=String.valueOf(newEmployee.getEmpFname())%>' />

System.out.println("newEmployee.getFname string value in loop: " +newEmployee.getEmpFname());

<%
}
%>

</aui:select>
```

It shows an a big empty list.

What should I do to get the values in the drop down list from the database?

Comment: do you get employe list in newEmployee.getEmpFname() var?

Comment: Ravi: I have set a a loop to go traverse through each employee :
Employee newEmployee = new EmployeeImpl();
    int totalEmployees = EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.getEmployeesCount();
                for(int i=0; i<totalEmployees;i++)
At each employee I try to get its fName..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can make out the following from the code you have given:

```
Employee newEmployee = new EmployeeImpl();
int totalEmployees = EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.getEmployeesCount();
```

This code is before the `for` loop, so what you are doing is you are just getting `total-count` instead of the actual list of `Employees`.

And here inside the for-loop:

```
<aui:option name = "opt" value ='<%=String.valueOf(newEmployee.getEmpFname())%>' />
```

you are just fetching an empty string `""` or `null` value through the code `newEmployee.getEmpFname()` since your `newEmployee` object is not from the database but is created in the JSP itself and hence a big empty list :-)

I think you need to return a `List<Employee>` also with the `totalEmployees` (total-count) from the database rather than creating a new instance and then just calling `.getEmpFname()` on that instance.

Answer (score -1):

```
enter code here

<aui:select id="empName" name="empName">
<%

int totalEmployees = EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.getEmployeesCount();

List<Employee> list=  EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.getEmployees(0, totalEmployees );

for(Employee employeeList: list)
{

%>  

<aui:option value="<%=employeeList.getEmployeeName()%>"><%=employeeList.getEmployeeName()%> </aui:option>   

<% 
System.out.println(employeeList.getEmployeeName());
%>

<%
}
%>
</aui:select>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Could you please add some more information to this answer?